# Подчеркивание с отступом

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Всем привет, помогите как можно сверстать данный элемент. Подчеркивание внизу появляется от наведения на элемент. Казалось бы ответ очевиден, но тогда при наведении через :hover { border: 2px solid black } допустим, надписи подвигаются вверх на 2 пикселя, можно ли как-то это реализовать другими способами?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: сделайте до наведения прозрачный бордер 2 пикселя, или box-sizing:border-box

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто дописать стили к нужному элементу без наведения сразу с нижним бордером, просто без цвета.

```
.elem {border-bottom: 2px solid inherit;}
```

И тогда элемент не будет прыгать